# GraphQL Login Schema

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, graphql

I'm getting error for my user.password and user.id

"Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any>'."
"Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any>'."

Any Idea how to fix this, i tried alrady to check is user.password is available and if not throw an error with

```
if(!user.password){
   throw new Error('User not found');
}
```

but getting the same error for user.password there...

My GraphQL Schema

```
import config from '../../config/config';
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString } from 'graphql';
import User from '../../models/userModel';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});

const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  fields: {
    // User Login
    login: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
      },
      async resolve(parent, args, res) {
        const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: args.email } });
        if (!user) {
          throw new Error('Password not found');
        }
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(args.password, user.password);
        if (!isMatch) {
          throw new Error('Invalid password');
        }
        const refresh_token = createRefreshToken({ id: user.id });

        res.cookie('refreshtoken', refresh_token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          path: '/user/refresh_token',
          maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 7 days
        });

        return { msg: 'Login success!' };
      },
    },
  },
});

interface jwt {
  id: string;
}

const createRefreshToken = (payload: jwt) => {
  return jwt.sign(payload, config.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: '7d',
  });
};
```

My userModel:

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../config/sequalize';

const User = sequelize.define(
  'user',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export default User;
```

I tried this code, but ending up by getting this error:

Cannot find name 'UserAttributes'.ts(2304)
type UserAttributes = /*unresolved*/ any

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../config/sequelize';

interface IUser {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}

interface UserInstance
  extends Sequelize.Model<UserAttributes>,
    UserAttributes {}

const User = sequelize.define<UserInstance, IUser>(
  "User",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  }
);
export { IUser, UserInstance };
export default User;
```

Comment: try create an interface for the User model that defines the properties of the model, including the password property. Then, you can use this interface in the UserType definition in your GraphQL schema.

Comment: I'm struggling creating one, may you help me by providing me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this an example of how you can define the User interface

```js
interface IUser {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}

interface UserInstance
  extends Sequelize.Model<IUser>,
    IUser {}

const User = sequelize.define<UserInstance, IUser>(
  "User",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  }
);
export { IUser, UserInstance };
export default User;
```

```js
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});
```

Comment: Im getting this error: Cannot find name 'UserAttributes'.ts(2304) type UserAttributes = /unresolved/ any

I got this error, i edit my post with the code i tried from you, maybe something wrong with imports?

Comment: sory , i write code in stackoverflow editor so , i don't see where the error , try now , i fix it

Comment: UserAttributes = IUser